# Static tableView cells not showing checkmark if out of view when view loads

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview controller that I am using as a preferences screen.  It has three sections, each with static cells.
The third section has 6 rows and each row represents a different date format, but depending on the device, not all appear when the view loads.
I am using the checkmark accessoryType to denote whether or not the particular option has been selected.  (I get that from my Realm database store)

In the tableview in IB, I set all cells to have accessoryType - .None so initially, no checkmarks.

When the view appears, I retrieve the stored value and set the appropriate checkmark like this.

```
 for (index,selDateFormat) in dateFormats.enumerate() {
   if selDateFormat == dateFormat {
         tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 2))?.accessoryType = .Checkmark
   } else {
          tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 2))?.accessoryType = .None
   }
```

}

It works great if the row is in view so on an iPhone 6 plus, I am great.  However, on an iPhone 4s, only the first two rows are shown in this section until I scroll.  The problem is that if I selected an option in rows 3 - 6, the checkmark is not displayed because it was out of view when the view appeared.
Is there a way that I can get the checkmark to show when the view appears?

Answer (score 0):

For those rows which are off screen, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will return nil.  You need to set the checkmark (or not) when the cells are created as the rows are scrolled on screen.  Override `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and set the checkmark as required:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    if let selDateRow = dateFormats.indexOf(selDateFormat) {
        if (indexPath.row == selDateRow) {
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = .None
        }
    } else { // just in case selDateFormat isn't in the dateFormats array...
        cell.accessoryType = .None
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer was even simpler in code

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    let section = indexPath.section
    if section == 2 {

        if dateFormats[indexPath.row] == dateFormat {
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = .None
        }

    }
    return cell
}
```